# Dynamic Update style sheet from javascript dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I have a small html page that has some javascript variables that are obtained from a small plc.  One of the variables is a temperature that changes.

My variables are :
temp4name
temp4ValFixed
temp4SetPoint
deltaTemp

These are all obtained in tempexampleTest_5.js and display on the HTML fine.

I have the foillowing code on my testTemp.html:

```
</label>
    <div id="temp4name" class="textStyleTitle">Probe</div>
    <div id="temp4SetPoint" class="textStyleSetpoint">Setpoint</div>
    <div id="deltaTemp" class="textStyleDelta">Delta</div> 

    <div id="temp4ValFixed" class="tempstyleSetpoint">0</div>   
}

</body>
<!--load and run our javascript-->
<script src="tempexampleTest_5.js"></script>
```

I have a stylesheet where i have defined the styles:

.textStyleTitle
.textStyleSetpoint
.textStyleDelta

and

```
.tempstyleSetpoint
{text-align: center; background-color: #000000;font: 520px Arial Black, sans-serif;
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

my variable deltaTemp = (temp4SetPoint-temp4ValFixed)

If deltaTemp ( > 1) then I want to either use a javascript vaiable to attrible in the change the stylesheet in
0 or change the color attibute in the .tempstyleSetpoint to #f25009.   I will have other changes but if I can change this one, I will be able to do the rest.

So basically I want to change the Text color on the HTML depending on the dynamic variable deltaTemp.

I have 3 files:
testTemp.html
tempexampleTest_5.js
tempstyleAll3.css

I have read about changing the color but I am so new I do not know where to put the code to do that.  I tried declaring a variable tCSS and changinging it in the tempexampleTest_5.js but when I out my variable in the 0, it was not taken as a stylesheet.

Comment: Are you willing to use libraries or frameworks? A good framework for actively updating variables is angular.js and a good library for manipulating  style and elements is jquery

Comment: Thanks, I will check angular.js  out.